# Adding an ID to a label tag in symfony form

Tags: forms, symfony

I am building a form in symfony2 and I need the label of a form element to have an ID so I can hide it using javascript.

Here is my code that builds the label:

```
    $builder->add(
        'campaign',
        'text',
        array('label' => 'Name of campaign / product being promoted')
    );
```

Is it possible to pass in a parameter to the array that will render an ID in the label tag?

If not, the label and form element is contained within a div tag. Is it possible to add an ID to the div?

It is currently rendered like this:

```
<div>
<label for="AddedValue_revenue_online">Total of added value revenue allocated to         online</label>

<input type="text" id="AddedValue_revenue_online" name="AddedValue[revenue_online]" required="required" value="" style="display: inline-block;">

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can specify the `label_attr` option which you can pass an array of attributes to.

In your example:

```
$builder->add(
    'campaign',
    'text',
    array('label' => 'Name of campaign / product being promoted',
          'label_attr' => array('id' => 'someID')))
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but I get the following error:  Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\CreationException' with message 'The option "label_attr" does not exist'

Comment: What version of Symfony are you using?

Comment: Sorry guys, my mistake! Im actually using Symfony 1. Is it possible to achieve this in Symfony 1?

Comment: Sorry I cannot help you. I had a look at the sources of Symfony 1.4.20 and there seems to be an attributes array to render label attributes but I could not find the spot where you specify the attributes. Maybe you want to consider switching to Symfony 2 anyway ;)